# How to elimate duplicate data being read from a url that refreshes in python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The snippet works already but I need help in filtering some duplicates results.

Issue #1: After running the script for few minutes, it displays duplicate result / the same results

Issue #2: Sometimes, it misses some data. Im not sure if this is normal

Goal #1: Eliminate duplicates / dont process if it has been read already

Goal #2: Possibly read all data in succession/continuity. (10205401, 10205402, 10205403, 10205404 and so on)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re, requests

trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')

url = "https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e&ps=100&p=1"
baseurl = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
scans = 0
previous_block = 0
while True:
    scans += 1
    reqtxsInternal = requests.get(url,header, timeout=2)
    souptxsInternal = BeautifulSoup(reqtxsInternal.content, 'html.parser')
    blocktxsInternal = souptxsInternal.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')
    print (" -> Whole Page Scanned: ", scans)
    for row in blocktxsInternal[1:]:
        txnhash = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:]
        txnhashdetails = txnhash.strip()
        block = row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:]
        if float(block) > float(previous_block):
            previous_block = block
        value = row.find_all('td')[9].text[0:]
        amount = trim.sub('', value).replace(",", "")
        transval = float(amount)
        
        if float(transval) >= 0 and block == previous_block:
            print ("    Processing data -> " + str(txnhashdetails)[60:] + "   " + str(block) + "   " + str(transval))
        else:
            pass
    
sleep(1)
```

Current Output: (After few minutes of running the script)

```
-> Whole Page Scanned:  14
 Processing data -> 8490f9   10205401   0.0
 Processing data -> 31f486   10205401   0.753749522929516
 Processing data -> 180ff9   10205401   0.0011
-> Whole Page Scanned:  15              <--- duplicate reads/data
 Processing data -> 8490f9   10205401   0.0                  
 Processing data -> 31f486   10205401   0.753749522929516
 Processing data -> 180ff9   10205401   0.0011
-> Whole Page Scanned:  16 >            <--- just fine
 Processing data -> 836486   10205402   0.0345
 Processing data -> d05a8a   10205402   1.37
 Processing data -> 0a035d   10205402   0.3742134
-> Whole Page Scanned:  17               <--- missed one (10205403)                   
 Processing data -> e9d7b7   10205404   10.10
 Processing data -> 9079c9   10205404   1.09
 Processing data -> f8a8a0   10205404   100.2
```

Comment: Have you checked the site's terms? https://bscscan.com/terms

Comment: Thank you for this info. I think I am just doing this "search indexing for display" or save it as a file for further processing.

Comment: How could you identify duplicate? By block id?

Comment: Yes, If you try running the script for a few minutes, it will read sometimes same block number/block id. I know sometimes perhaps the refresh might be late and it should just pass reading same data

Comment: better use the api of bscscan

Comment: @rbutrnz your user agent looks a bit cheap so easy to detect. Maybe try a more rigorous one

Comment: One more question, what is the purpose of `previous_block`?

Comment: previous_block basically saves the current block being read so that, hopefully it will not read again the same block if ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to improve the snippet and it no longer reads again same data. As for the data read skips, I think it has something to do with the refreshes of the page. Sometimes, the data read is long and when it rescans, two or more blocks has passed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re, requests

trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')

#-- check latest block
url = "https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e&ps=100&p=1"
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
reqtxsInternal = requests.get(url,header, timeout=2)
souptxsInternal = BeautifulSoup(reqtxsInternal.content, 'html.parser')
blocktxsInternal = souptxsInternal.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr', limit=2)#[1:]
for row in blocktxsInternal[1:]:
    startblock = int(row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:])
#-- check latest block

scans = 0
prev_block = int(startblock - 1)
while True:
    scans += 1
    url = "https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e&ps=100&p=1"
    header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
    reqtxsInternal = requests.get(url,header, timeout=2)
    souptxsInternal = BeautifulSoup(reqtxsInternal.content, 'html.parser')
    blocktxsInternal = souptxsInternal.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')
    for row in blocktxsInternal[1:]:
        txnhash = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:]
        txnhashdetails = txnhash.strip()
        block = int(row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:])
        value = row.find_all('td')[9].text[0:]
        amount = trim.sub('', value).replace(",", "")
        transval = float(amount)
        if (block >= prev_block):
            if (transval >= 0):
                print("Process Data -> " + str(txnhashdetails)[60:] + "  "  + str(block) + " " + str(transval))
                prev_block = block
        elif int(block < int(block)-1):           
            pass         
        else:
            continue
    print (" -> Whole Page Scanned: " + str(scans) + "   " + str(prev_block))
    sleep(1)
    print ()
```

Current Output:

```
Process Data -> 7972bd  10374519 2.4
 -> Whole Page Scanned: 1   10374519

Process Data -> 1f2166  10374520 1.055826801385845
 -> Whole Page Scanned: 2   10374520

Process Data -> 2a88c9  10374522 2.48
Process Data -> ebb114  10374522 1.42
 -> Whole Page Scanned: 3   10374522

Process Data -> 9c1fd0  10374523 2.49
Process Data -> b6a747  10374523 12.92714512958549
 -> Whole Page Scanned: 4   10374523

Process Data -> 159878  10374524 5.2134
Process Data -> 73c759  10374524 5.0
 -> Whole Page Scanned: 5   10374524

Process Data -> d01ca7  10374526 2.0
Process Data -> 8138eb  10374526 3.87
Process Data -> fcd3f3  10374526 1.471087011043643
 -> Whole Page Scanned: 6   10374526

Process Data -> 464e13  10374527 1.0
Process Data -> faa9c9  10374527 2.2
Process Data -> b9ee22  10374527 1.803
 -> Whole Page Scanned: 7   10374527
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this one a try.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re, requests

trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')

url = "https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e&ps=100&p=1"
baseurl = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
scans = 0
recorded_blocks = []
while True:
    scans += 1
    reqtxsInternal = requests.get(url,header, timeout=2)
    souptxsInternal = BeautifulSoup(reqtxsInternal.content, 'html.parser')
    blocktxsInternal = souptxsInternal.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')

    for row in blocktxsInternal[1:]:
        txnhash = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:]
        txnhashdetails = txnhash.strip()
        block = row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:]
        
        value = row.find_all('td')[9].text[0:]
        amount = trim.sub('', value).replace(",", "")
        transval = float(amount)
        
        if (float(block),float(transval))  not in recorded_blocks:
            recorded_blocks.append((float(block),float(transval)))
            if float(transval) >= 1:
                print ("Doing something with the data -> " + str(block) + "   " + str(transval))
            else:
                pass
       
    print (" -> Whole Page Scanned: ", scans)
    sleep(1)
```